# How do I use Applescript to log me in to heroku console and count my users?

Tags: terminal, applescript, heroku

My script looks like this, really simple

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd myapp"
    do script "heroku console" in window 1
    do script "User.count" in window 1
end tell
```

But I get an "Error in the AppleEvent Routine". What is wrong with this script? If I type the commands in the Terminal it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably not working because `heroku console` doesn't return you to the shell after it finishes, it starts the interactive console.

What you need is something that will run and return. Fortunately this is totally possible with Heroku:

```
heroku console 'User.count'
```

You can call `console` with a command to run as the argument. Then it returns the result immediately instead of starting up the interactive session. Sounds perfect for you!

Answer (score 0):

This command means nothing... cd myapp. You have to give the full path to myapp like ~/myapp. Also you should run them as 1 command by putting a semicolon between them...

```
tell application "Terminal"
    do script "cd path/to/myapp; heroku console; User.count"
end tell
```

Comment: hmmm, the User.count command doesn't work. Maybe the remote heroku console doesn't accept Applescript commands?